# Dailymotion api fetch video info with json and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I need some help because after reading the dailymotion api and multiple sources couldn't figure out what was the problem.
i am trying to fetch data from dailymotion fro a specific video id by:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.dailymotion.com/video/' + encodeURIComponent(videoid) + '?fields=title,duration,user&callback=?', function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        console.log(item);
   });
});
```

but keep responding:

```
"Invalid parameter `_' for `GET /video/<id>'"
```

but the problem is that when trying to hit the same url to the browser i take a response of json.

I tried to make it work with .getScript function but again no result.

```
$.getScript('https://api.dailymotion.com/video/' + encodeURIComponent(videoid) + '?fields=title,duration,user&callback=dailymotion_fetch_data_callback');
```

and after that to read it through :

```
function dailymotion_fetch_data_callback(data) {
 $.each(data, function(i, item){
    console.log(item);
});
}
```

Can you please help me and show me a way how i can read the json respond after pushing data to a callback function?

Comment: Based on the error message alone, it seems as though `encodeURIComponent(videoid)` is returning '_'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. this is not the case because i tried to change that and give a fix id than a variable but the problem seems to be irrelevant with the id.
As i said if i take the generated url and paste it to a browser i take a well structed json.

Comment: Can you put your code up on jsfiddle? Also, out of curiosity, have you checked to see if this might somehow be a known issue with their API?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ehxxn/1/ 

It seems that nobody had problems with that. I have found one or two questions on internet and the answers are not helping.

Comment: ok - for starters remove `callback=?` from your query string. That's messing things up, and is unnecessary given that you have defined an anonymous function to handle the output.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ehxxn/3/ this is the correct i had some typos

Comment: if i remove the callback=? then i will not be able to fetch data through ajax because this is not alloed due to different origin script.
callback=? gives the ability to take respond as jsonp and not having issues with cross-domain ajax request.

Answer (score 3):

When using JSONP (json with a callback), the `$.getJSON` function appends the parameter *={timestamp} (hence the invalid parameter '*' error) to your query to help prevent caching by using a different URL. You can disable this but you'll need to use the `$.ajax` syntax instead. Unfortunately this might cause your request to be cached by the browser. You might find another way by seeing what you can find in the `$.ajax` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"https://api.dailymotion.com/video/" + encodeURIComponent(videoid) + "?fields=title,duration,user",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item){
            console.log(item);
       });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you would handle this with a callback using JSONP (reference http://jsfiddle.net/Ehxxn/6/)

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xlu5dd?fields=title,duration,user&callback=handleData"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function handleData(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item){
            $('#result').append(item);
       });
 }
```